# VS 2010 c++ paths showing up in project properties but not in the *.vcxprojf or *.sln files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

On one computer when we open the properties of a MFC C++ project, the project properties C/C++ - General - Other include directories, contains paths at the beginning which should not be there, because they are not in the *.vcxproj file. We would like to know where these path are coming from.

We checked environment variables: include, path. No error there.

Tx.

Comment: Check via menu Tools->Options, from the pop up menu dialog go to 'Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories' then may be coming from there

Comment: No nothing there. I am reading an article about Microsoft.cpp..users.props files. Trying to find them

Answer (score 3):

Culprit file located in:

C:\Documents and Settings(user)\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props